# Black-box debugging .NET application

Tags: .net, windows

I have a .NET application received from a vendor, running on a Windows 7 virtual machine. The application submits data to their web endpoint using TLS.

We are supposed to replicate the behaviour of this application.  Unfortunately, it's unclear what is being sent by the tool (is it XML? is it encoded base64?).

I've attempted to decrypt the SSL traffic using Wireshark, but that only seems to work with browsers that can dump the session keys.

Is there a way to debug this compiled .NET application, to get a better understanding of how it works, and what it's sending?  Hopefully, without using a disassembler?

Comment: Have you tried decompiling it with ILSpy, dotPeek, or similar? .NET applications decompile very easily. This is the best way, unless you need to "clean-room" the implementation, for copyright or patent reasons. Just noticed you said "hopefully without using a disassembler" - can you clarify why not, as it's definitely the best option all-things-being-equal.

Comment: Alternatively, if the traffic is being sent by HTTPS, use Fiddler to perform a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: If it's not HTTPS, you can look into [SSLsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit). I've not used this myself though, but it should be able to MITM any arbitrary TLS traffic.

Comment: Finally, the reason that disassembly is the best option is that the data may not be human-readable XML or JSON, or similar. It might be some proprietary binary format, which is going to be much harder to reverse-engineer without disassembly.

Comment: Great advice, thanks @RB, fiddler solved it for me.  If you put that into an answer I'll give you credit

Comment: Done - out of curiosity though, why do you prefer not to decompile the assembly and see exactly what it's doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fiddler to perform a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attack on the HTTPS traffic.

Launch Fiddler and click "Tools -> Options"

Then select the highlighted options. You will be warned about adding a "Fiddler_DO_NOT_TRUST" certificate to your certificate store. Install the certificate (obviously it's recommended that you use a sandbox virtual machine or similar, not a development or production machine).

[image]